# How to authenticate socket.io connection without underlying useragent to keep the cookies and persist the session

Tags: node.js, session, testing, socket.io, mocha.js

I'm trying to  test an app's socket.io which uses passport.socketio to authenticate the socket connection

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:' + app.PORT);
```

This does not work because there's no accompanying cookie.

Even if I get the cookie from a persisted superagent session

```
var cookie;
var agent = request.agent(app);
agent.post('/login').send('credentials').end(function(err, res) {
    cookie = res.req._headers.cookie;
});
```

where/how do I use it ?

I [found](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/search?q=cookie&ref=cmdform&type=Issues) that there are already quite a few requests for socket.io-client to add cookie support

http://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/450
http://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/439
http://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/344

but I don't see them going anywhere.

Is there any other solution to use persistent cookie session with socket while testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie data could be passed using querystring

```
agent.post('/login').send('credentials').end(function(err, res) {
    cookie = res.req._headers.cookie.replace(/=/g, '%3D');   //escape '=' 
});

socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost' + '/?cookie=' + cookie);
```

It becomes available in the server socket

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, callback){
    handshakeData._query.cookie;
});
```

And so it can be used to perform authorization. Since I was using passport.socketio, it plays nicely [with a little change to check this query string instead of headers.](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio/issues/65)